# Metricbeat not show volume mount under dev filesystem

Tags: elasticsearch, filesystems, grafana, volume, metricbeat

Let me explain the problem and context. This is a server for a database solution. The database was created with docker, and added a volume to the server. Then all docker installation path was moved to the volume added to the server (for security and backup mantain). Then for monitoring, i added a metricbeat agent to capture data, like disk and other stuff, but for this context occurs the problem.

Im searching for a specific mount (the is a volume mount), and when in terminal type **df -aTh | grep "/dev"** for show filesystem, its show this image:

[image]

Then in metricbeat.yaml i have this configuration for system module:

```
- module: system
  period: 30s
  metricsets: ["filesystem"]
  processors:
   - drop_event.when.regexp:
       system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|etc|host|hostfs)($|/)'
```

Notice in last line i omitted "**dev**" , because i want to obtain the mount volume "/dev/sda" high lighted in the screen shot. But when i discoverd in kibana, that device is not showed, and i dont now why, must be showed.

[image]

Thanks for reading and help :) . All of this if for monitoring, and show data in grafana. But i can't find the filesystem "/dev/sda/", for the disk dashboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation about the setting `filesystem.ignore_types`:

> A list of filesystem types to ignore. Metrics will not be collected from filesystems matching these types. This setting also affects the fsstats metricset. **If this option is not set, metricbeat ignores** all types for virtual devices in systems where this information is available (e.g. **all types marked as nodev in `/proc/filesystems` in Linux systems**). This can be set to an empty list ([]) to make filebeat report all filesystems, regardless of type.

If you check the file `/proc/filesystems` you can see which files are marked as "nodev". Is it possible that ext4 is marked as nodev?

Can you try to set the setting `filesystem.ignore_types: []` to see if the file is now considered?

Comment: It's works. First of all thank you. So, i did what you said, i added to metricbeat the module system, "filesystem.ignore_type", and put in that array all the values for ignore except the one i needed "/dev/sda", and work like a charm.. you make my week :)